# Prevent Double submit jquery validation ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery.validate.js to validate my form, the query I'm using is working, everything is working there one thing that I can't find a fix for it

```
<div id="form">
   <form>
       <div class="form-group">
      Input, radio, textarea
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-black" id="next">Continue</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

when the user click on Continue the form gets validated and is "submitted", the thing is that I don't need to submit the form just yet, to sort of prevent that I did the following:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#packs").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
        $("#summary").html("Erros");
    }).validate({
        debug: false,
        errorElement: "em",
        errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent("div"));
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.text("ok!").addClass("success flosts");
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $("#enviaforms").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#rebvs").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#revisa").click(function(){
                $("#rebvs").fadeOut("slow");
                $.ajax({
                    type: $(form).attr('method'),
                    url: $(form).attr('action'),
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    dataType : 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
                        $("#respuesta").fadeIn("slow");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        console.log();
                        alert("Error please try again...");
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.sts == true) {
                        $(".loading").fadeOut( "slow" );
                        $("#enviaforms").fadeOut("slow");
                        $("#respuesta").html(data.datas.valids);
                        // $(form).reset();
                        // alert(data.datas.valids);
                    } else {
                        $(".loading").fadeOut( "slow" );
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $("#editar").click(function(){
                $("#enviaforms").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#rebvs").fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
            })
        },
        rules: { ... },
        messages: {...}
     });
   });
```

If you notice on my submitHandler function I have other id's what it does is, hide the form and show another div outside the form with all the users personal data and other settings for the user to review, on that other div I have two buttons, one would be to actually submit the form but remember that the buttons are outside the form
Submit form and Edit form, this two buttons are outside the form and I'm calling it by using the .click() function... if user click on Edit form, it hide review div and shows the form, when user click on submit form it actually submit the form via ajax. 
Resume:
The clicks the user made to submit the formation..

> [Fill form]Continue -> [Review form all ok]Submit Form = Perfect execution, we all happy...
>
> [Form]Continue -> [Go back to edit form]Edit Form -> [After edit]Continue -> [all ok]Submit form = Not ok, it send double submit...  :(

So, **the question is how do I prevent the double submit** only when user go back to edit then return to the review and then submit the form...

I think that the problem is the "continue" button since it is pressed twice but, how do I validate the form without it?... If I use an A tag to go to the next phase the form doesn't get validated in full if the form has error and the by the time the user hits the submit button sure it will trow some errors but the user wont see them since the errors are inside the form and by that time the form is hidden so no errors are shown and I need to shows any error before anything else... 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [.valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) of validator in order to check if your form is valid without submitting it.

`validator.valid();// it will check if all your fields are valid without submitting anything.`

From there the workflow can continue as you like sending the form whenever you like.

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't be `validator` unless `validator` represents the _form_ object.  `$('#myform').valid()`